# How to save poll get and save poll results on HTML

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, web-services

I am a little confused on this. I am making a web using HTML/CSS.
I have some JQUERY things in there such as SlideShow.
I wanted to add a poll in there but I am not sure how I would save it and load it.

I wanted to do it the easiest way possible.

I'm also not sure where to save the result. I was thinking when a user clicks "Submit", it would save the information to a text file, and it'll get result from that also.

I could also use a database I guess.

Anyone know how I would be able to do this ?
Any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a poll is not going to be a simple task if you are not using some sort of CMS platform (like wordpress or joomla for example) and some extension such a platform might offer.

As far as the best method for storing / retrieving data, a database is the far more common (and easier) compared to writing data to a text file.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp is a good place to start if you are new to database interaction with php and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Got to http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp and learn how to use ajax.

Send data from the html via javascript to a simple php script. Write to sqlite or even mysql, and retrieve data the same way. Instant poll! And then you can learn (or have someone else do it for you) proper security and error handling for a sound and stable user experience :)

For better details you'd have to give us the scope of the web you are building!

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can achieve that is with a database. It will save you a lot of time and a lot of coding.

- For starters you should read this nice [TUTORIAL](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) about PDO or MySQLi, but i personally recommend PDO which is much more easy to use and easy to understand.
- Next step is the information you load on that poll and how you send it to the processor that inserts it in the database, make sure you make the form as readable by YOU as you can, because you will process it and you will save it and also you will read it to display on clients browser.
- there are tons of examples on the internet, open Google and search.
- make sure you optimize your HTML code and your PHP code, even if you are writing for your site/blog, in 2-3 years you won't understand what you did there if the code is not well formatted or properly indented.
- there is no easiest way.